# Creating Table in Word Docx using python Index Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

the problem is that I cannot seem to create a table in my Word Document, despite being able to prior. The problem has an issue selecting which row/column to write to in the table.

The error code produced is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

And is found in the line:
`cell=table.cell(l,0)`

Here is the offending for loop:

```
    for k in myresults:
        l=l+1
        list(k)
        print(k)
        print("FF")
        print(k[0])
        print(l)
        cell=table.cell(l,0)
        cell.text=k[0]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        StockDeficit=int(k[3])-int(k[2])
        cell=table.cell(l,1)
        cell.text=k[1]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        cell=table.cell(l,2)
        cell.text=k[2]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        cell=table.cell(l,3)
        cell.text=k[3]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        #Remove £ From Cost
        CostOfBadges = k[1].replace("£", "")
        CostOfBadges=float(CostOfBadges)*StockDeficit
        CostOfBadges=round(CostOfBadges,2)
        cell=table.cell(l,4)
        cell.text=str(CostOfBadges)
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        TotalCost=TotalCost+CostOfBadges
        print(TotalCost)
        TotalCost=round(TotalCost,2)
```

This loop is part of a larger function, so if you require that I can edit the question

The expected result is that the table is written to the file.

Example:

[image: Badge Table]

The actual result is that the program errors, producing:

> IndexError: list index out of range

In the line:

```
cell=table.cell(l,0)
```

Full function below as requested:

```
def CreateStockReport():
    global TotalCostG
    TotalCostG=0
    RowCount=0
    #Open Report File
    doc = docx.Document()
    run = doc.add_paragraph().add_run()
    # Apply Style
    Tstyle = doc.styles['Normal']
    font = Tstyle.font
    font.name = "Nunito Sans"
    font.size = Pt(48)
    Title = doc.add_paragraph()
    TRun = Title.add_run("Badge Stock Report")
    TRun.bold = True
    doc.add_picture('Scouts_Logo_Stack_Black.png', width=Inches(4.0))
    TotalCost=0
    mycursor.execute("SELECT badgename,cost,stock, desiredstock FROM badges")
    myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
    #Create Table
    #Determine How Long The Table Will Be
    for i in myresults:
        if i[2]<i[3]:
            RowCount=RowCount+1
            print("No Of Rows:"+str(RowCount))
    RowCount=RowCount+1
    doc.add_page_break()
    table = doc.add_table(rows=RowCount, cols=5)
    table.style = 'Table Grid'
    for l in range(0,5):
        print(l)
        cell = table.cell(0, l)
        if l==0:
            cell.text="Badge Name"
        if l==1:
            cell.text="Cost (£)"
        if l==2:
            cell.text="Stock"
        if l==3:
            cell.text="Desired Stock Level"
        if l==4:
            cell.text="Price Of Order (£)"
        TableHeadings = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableHeadings.font.bold = True
        TableHeadings.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableHeadings.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)


    print(len(myresults))
    TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
    TableText.font.bold = False
    TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
    TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
    NoOfStocked = 0
    for k in myresults:
        #Remove Unneccesary rows (Badges which meet stock requirements)
        print(k[2])
        print(k[3])
        if int(k[2])>int(k[3]):
            myresults.remove(k)
            print(myresults)
            NoOfStocked=NoOfStocked+1
    print("Number Of Stocked Badges"+str(NoOfStocked))
    print(myresults)
    l=0
    for k in myresults:
        l=l+1
        list(k)
        print(k)
        print("FF")
        print(k[0])
        print(l)
        cell=table.cell(l,0)
        cell.text=k[0]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        StockDeficit=int(k[3])-int(k[2])
        cell=table.cell(l,1)
        cell.text=k[1]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        cell=table.cell(l,2)
        cell.text=k[2]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        cell=table.cell(l,3)
        cell.text=k[3]
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        #Remove £ From Cost
        CostOfBadges = k[1].replace("£", "")
        CostOfBadges=float(CostOfBadges)*StockDeficit
        CostOfBadges=round(CostOfBadges,2)
        cell=table.cell(l,4)
        cell.text=str(CostOfBadges)
        TableText = cell.paragraphs[0].runs[0]
        TableText.font.bold = False
        TableText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
        TableText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
        TotalCost=TotalCost+CostOfBadges
        print(TotalCost)
        TotalCost=round(TotalCost,2)
    TotalCostG = TotalCost
    Total = doc.add_paragraph()
    TotalText = Total.add_run("The total amount for this order is £"+str(TotalCost))
    TotalText.font.name = 'Nunito Sans'
    TotalText.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Report Created!")
    doc.save("BadgeStockReport.docx")
    os.system("start BadgeStockReport.docx")
```

Comment: you don't have all the code so is difficult, in any case I can see that you did l=l+1 but what is l? I hope you declared for example l=0 before the loop or it could create problems

Comment: @Carlo1585 I will add the entire function.

Comment: mmm I never used python with word but in some example of the documentation I notice that they specify row and column in this way: table.Cell(Row = 1, Column= 1) instead you do table.cell(l,0); i'm not sure if it's the same but try it ;)

Comment: @Carlo1585 No that didn't help, but thanks for your input ;)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the code is to take rows from the DataBase and insert into the table in Word document. Number of rows in the table depends on the condition `if i[2]<i[3]`.
That mean if element3 (it's i[2]) less than element4 (it's i[3]) then new empty row will be added to the table (`RowCount=RowCount+1`).

For example.
Right after the line `myresults=mycursor.fetchall()`
insert this line: `myresults = [('Winston', '1', '2', '3'), ('Julia', '1', '2', '3')]`

and launch the program, it should work,
because i[2] (string '2') less than i[3] (string '3'). The condition '2' < '3' is true both times.
Everything is ok, two new rows are added, and later two lines of data added to these rows.

Now change just one value (3 to 101): `myresults = [('Winston', '1', '2', '101'), ('Julia', '1', '2', '3')]`

and launch the program, it shouldn't work.
The condition '2' < '101' is not true (and it's not a doublethink, this is because of string comparison rules, string started with '1' is less than string started with '2'). So one row is not created at the table, and later two lines of data need two rows, but the row is only one.

The error message `IndexError: list index out of range`
means no row with such index in the table.

So as solution you could convert string to float before the condition. If the problem not in string comparison rules but in numbers, you need to rethink the algorithm.

You could provide result of the sql request ("`SELECT badgename,cost,stock, desiredstock FROM badges`") here.
You can print this, right after the line `myresults=mycursor.fetchall()`
insert this line: `print(mycursor.fetchall())`. Or show as `tk.messagebox.showinfo`. Or check right in the DB.

No need to show all the data, two last elements (i[2], i[3]) need to be checked.

Let's look at this.